# Traversing of table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I am new to jquery I stuck in table traversing.I know simple traversing but I dont in this how to do it. my code is:

```
<div id="compare">
    <table>
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="stock4">
                <td>
                    <img src="abc.jpg" alt="">
                </td>
                <td class="price">
                    <div>
                        <span class="prc">1000</span>
                        <div class="variant">
                            <table>
                                <thead></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="stock4">
                                        <td class="price"><span class="prc">2000</span></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want the price only 1000 not price from variant div and also I want image src.I dont need a price from variant div.How can I do it.

Comment: Would be much simpler to wrap the `1000` in an element like `<span>` with a class on it. Beyond both the objective and the question are too vague. Take some time to read [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could use the ":first" pseudo-class like so:

`$('#compare tr .prc:first').text()`

Comment: is it possible to traverse without span class??

Comment: yes, but it makes it a bit more clunky. you could use something like this:

```$('#compare div:first')[0].firstChild.textContent.trim()```

But this relies on using the basic DOM functions instead of jQuery